# Can't set height of Angular Material Toast

Tags: css, angularjs, height, angular-material, toast

I would like to set the height of md-toast but when I set height in an inline style it just raises the bottom of where the toast is rendered and does not affect the actual height of toast container.

I've tired this:

```
 <md-toast style="height:100px;">
```

Here is my plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/k7lXAn?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template adds an extra div that isn't affected by the height of the parent md-toast.

Adding this override in the css file fixes it (in Chrome at least):

```
md-toast .md-toast-content {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @haakon319 Glad to hear it. Make it an accepted answer if you feel it solves your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your codes related to md-toast are inside the ng-template. Since those are templates, you can use them directly in your html code. Once you do that, the problem is fixed. I have modified your code. Here's the [plunk][1]:

```
   [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/nkuSGf?p=preview
```

Comment: This plunk when run shows the toast div at the bottom before being triggered?